# Why images don't appear in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, icons, jlabel

I watched a tutorial on how to create a GUI application in Java using javax.swing on YouTube and decided to create my own. I can't see images that I added to JLabel and I don't know to fix it. There is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame {
    final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1550, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 838;
    Frame (String title){
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize((int)(SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.8), (int)(SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.8));
        this.setLocation((SCREEN_WIDTH-(int)(SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.8))/2, (SCREEN_HEIGHT - (int)(SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.8))/2);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        validate();
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame frame = new Frame("Goul");

        ImageIcon kaneki = new ImageIcon("kaneki.png");
        frame.setIconImage(kaneki.getImage());

        ImageIcon test1 = new ImageIcon("test1.png");

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setIcon(test1);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.RIGHT);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
        frame.add(label);

    }
}
```

[There is a screenshot after running a program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1GUy.png)

Comment: Component must be added to the frame BEFORE making the frame visible.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
frame.pack();
```

After you add your label.

I would avoid naming your class Frame since that is used by `java.awt`.  It is standard practice for Frames to hold other components and the other components hold images and such.  I recommend using a JPanel for this.  Here is an example.

```
public class ShowImage extends JPanel {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Goul");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // start the program get out of the mains's static context.
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> new ShowImage().start());
    }
    public void start() {
                ImageIcon test1 = new ImageIcon("h:/Mars.png");
                JLabel label = new JLabel();
                label.setIcon(test1);
                label.setText("Image of Mars");
                label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.RIGHT);
                label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
                add(label);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(this);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //center on screen.
                frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Better would be to rearrange your statements so the last things you do is

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

That way, the screen won't, flutter while it positions the windows.

Comment: The frame logic should not be part of the ShowImage class. The ShowImage class should not know anything about the parent container it is added to. This way the panel could be added to a frame, dialog or another panel. The main() method should create the panel and then add it to a newly created instance of JFrame.

Comment: It didn't help. I still can't see images

Comment: @dalvol.amsi did you specify the complete path/file name for the image? Apparently `ImageIcon` will not throw an exception if it can't find the image.

Comment: @camickr  Fine.  But I was simply trying to get the OP a solution to their problem.  There are *many* proper design considerations when writing a gui or graphics program.  Imho, there is no need at this level to get into such detail.  My approach is perfectly in line with many of the Java Tutorials.

Comment: @WJS my images are placed in the same package as the main class, but your advice to specify the absolute path worked out

Comment: @dalvol.amsi glad it helped.  Imo, not throwing an exception in `ImageIcon` for this is a bug.   I'm running Java 18.0.2.1.  But this apparently has been around for a long time so there must be a reason it is still permitted.  Perhaps `camickr` can shed some light.